# Upload product with attribute in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, upload

I want to upload product with an attribute in Magento 2 with CSV file.
Can anyone tell me it is possible to upload a product with an attribute?

Comment: Yes, if the attribute is already created you just need to add a new column in your csv file with the attribute code.

Comment: The easiest way to proceed is by creating one product inside Magento and then export it. In this way, you have the exact structure in which you need to create the file to upload other products. Just add new lines to the file and follow the order of the fields.

Comment: I have attribute csv file so I want to upload it

Answer (score 1):

You will also need to make an adjustment of the image file (if they are not named correspondingly to the style number/SKU). Be prepared to go back and forth to configure the issue, but usually, the error messages are pretty self-explanatory.